# Unresolved reference while adding 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, opencsv, apache-commons-logging, android-studio-3.0

I'm adding opencsv on my android app, I'm usying Android Studio 3.0.
On gradle sync an error occours saying :
"Failed to resolve: commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2" as in the image:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9FnI.png)

These are the lines of my .gradle:

```
....
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10'
```

Even adding the jar manually by:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html
implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10'
```

I still get the error.
These are the repos

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: I found a solution that make sync succed: 
'    compile ('com.opencsv:opencsv:3.10')
    {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    }
'
I'll keep it like this, but I don't know if it may cause unexpected behaviours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830463/cant-add-dependency-to-android-project

For reference